# Xamarin C# console project not showing variables in locals window during debug

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, console-application

When I debug my console application it no longer shows variables in the locals window. When I hover over any variables I get the message "Unknown Identifier". I have researched this problem and it seems to go back to 2013 and many questions refer to app building. I have updated to the latest version (6.1.4) and it still exists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Console apps belong to Mono, not Xamarin. Did you compile as Release build? Release builds can have certain variables removed by optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I use the Xamarin studio application, so wrongly tagged it as Xamarin. As for the build, no, it has always been compiled as a debug build.